# Symfony 3 - replace string after render view (annotation)

Tags: symfony, templates, replace, annotations, render

I need replace string in view after rendered.
My all controllere use annotaion @Template("path").

My controller:

```
...
class AboutController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/about-us", name="about")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template("@AppBundle/Resources/views/About/index.html.twig")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
    }
}
...
```

I know to do it without annotaion:

```
...
class AboutController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/about-us", name="about")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $content = $this->renderView('AppBundle/Resources/views/About/index.html.twig', []);
        $content = str_replace('my text', 'my new text', $content);

        return new Response($content);
    }
}
...
```

How I can do it with annotaion (@template)?

Comment: Doesn't it make more sense to use variables inside your twig files?

Comment: webiste is big and I must replace all links to js hash when link is another domain :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use **Symfony's Event system**  [onKernelResponse](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/events.html#kernel-response)

This will allow you to grab the response after controller action return it and modify the response before sending it.

To subscribe an event follow [Syfmony's doc example](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/event_dispatcher.html#using-event-subscribers).
You did not tell us which version of Symfony you are using, those links are **3.4**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good solution! Thanks!